# not able to shift current process id to child process id

Tags: c, multiprocessing, createprocess

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

WinSockStartup();

//declarations
char data[255]=" server data",buff[255];
int len,port,ch,y=1,n=0, no_of_threads=0,CP_ret=0;//,Sel_ret=0,itr=0,max_fd;
struct sockaddr_in new_addr;
int sockfd,data_len_recv=-1,on=1,accfd=0,len_addr,data_len_send=-1;

//file writing attributes
char FileName[1024],logdata[1024];
SYSTEMTIME st;

//setting initial values
memset(&new_addr,0,sizeof(new_addr));
memset(&sockfd,0,sizeof(int));
memset(&accfd,0,sizeof(int));
memset(&len_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr),sizeof(int));
memset(&port,0,sizeof(int));
memset(buff,0,sizeof(buff));

//create process atrribute
STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi_child,pi_parent,pi_current;
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO) );
    si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    ZeroMemory( &pi_child, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );
ZeroMemory( &pi_parent, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION) );


//select attributes
struct timeval soctimeval;
soctimeval.tv_sec = 20;
soctimeval.tv_usec = 0;
fd_set read_fd_set;
FD_ZERO(&read_fd_set);

printf("enter the port number\n");
scanf("%d",&port);

new_addr.sin_family= AF_INET;
for(int y=0;y<7;y++)
    new_addr.sin_zero[y]= 0;
new_addr.sin_port=htons(port);
new_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");


//get parent process id
pi_parent.dwProcessId= GetCurrentProcessId();


//socket making
sockfd =socket(new_addr.sin_family, SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

if(sockfd==-1)
{
    printf("error in opening socket  %d \n",WSAGetLastError());
}
    else
        printf("Socket made Successfully\n");

setsockopt(sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(char *)&on,sizeof(on));

//bind socket
if((bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&new_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr)))==-1)
{
    printf("bind  error  %d \n",WSAGetLastError());

}
    else
        printf("Binded Successfully\n");

//listen socket
if( listen(sockfd,10)==-1)
{
    printf("Error in listening  %d \n",WSAGetLastError());
    }
else
    printf("Listened Successfully\n");

while(1)
{           
//accept
    accfd= accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&new_addr,&len_addr);
    if(accfd==-1)
    {
        printf("error in accept  %d \n",WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else
        printf("Accepted Successfully\n");

    //creating child process for multiple clients
    no_of_threads ++;
    printf("client no:  %d\n",no_of_threads);

    CP_ret=CreateProcess(TEXT("C:\\Users\\richa-a\\Desktop\\create_process_multiclient1\\client_server\\Debug\\server_tcp.exe"),
                        NULL,
                        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
                        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
                        (BOOL)1,            // Set handle inheritance to TRUE
                        DETACHED_PROCESS,   // No creation flags
                        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
                        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
                        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                        &pi_child );  

    pi_current.dwProcessId=GetCurrentProcessId(); //even after the create process. the current id is still of the parent.

    if(pi_parent.dwProcessId==pi_current.dwProcessId || CP_ret==0)
    {
        printf("\nparent id is %d\n",pi_parent.dwProcessId);
        printf("process id of child is %d \n",pi_child.dwProcessId);
        printf("process id of current function is %d \n",pi_current.dwProcessId);
        printf("child is nt running the code\n");
    }

    //pi_current.dwProcessId=GetCurrentProcessId();

    if(pi_child.dwProcessId==pi_current.dwProcessId)
    {

        //opening file
        GetLocalTime (&st);
                     sprintf(FileName,"D:\\Serve_Client\\Child_Process_%d_%d__%d.%d.%d.%d.log",st.wDay,st.wMonth,st.wHour,st.wMinute,st.wSecond,st.wMilliseconds);
        Child_FPtr=fopen(FileName,"wb");
        sprintf(logdata,"logging start for client %d\n",no_of_threads);
        LogInfo(logdata);
        //fwrite(logdata,sizeof(logdata),sizeof(logdata),Child_FPtr);


        sprintf(logdata,"process id of parent is %d\n",pi_parent.dwProcessId);
        LogInfo(logdata);
        sprintf(logdata,"process id of child is %d \n",pi_child.dwProcessId);
        LogInfo(logdata);
        sprintf(logdata,"process id of current function is %d \n",pi_current.dwProcessId);
        LogInfo(logdata);
        sprintf(logdata,"child is running the code\n");
        LogInfo(logdata);

        //recv data
        data_len_recv=recv(accfd,(char *)buff, sizeof(buff)-1,0);
        buff[data_len_recv]='\0';
        sprintf(logdata,"%s",buff);
        LogInfo(logdata);
        if(data_len_recv==sizeof(buff))
        {
            sprintf(logdata,"data rev Successfully\n");
            LogInfo(logdata);
            sprintf(logdata,"Recv data: %s\n",buff);
            LogInfo(logdata);
        }
        else if(data_len_recv<sizeof(buff))
        {
            sprintf(logdata,"hlf data rev Successfully\n");
            LogInfo(logdata);
            sprintf(logdata,"Recv data: %s\n",buff);
            LogInfo(logdata);
        }
        else if(data_len_recv==-1 || data_len_recv==0)
        {
            sprintf(logdata,"error in recv %d \n",WSAGetLastError());
            LogInfo(logdata);
        }

        //send data
        data_len_send=send(accfd,(const char *)data, sizeof(data),0);
        if(data_len_send==sizeof(data))
        {
            sprintf(logdata,"data send Successfully\n");
            LogInfo(logdata);
            sprintf(logdata,"data Send: %s\n",data);
            LogInfo(logdata);
        }
        else if(data_len_send<sizeof(data)&& data_len_send!=0)
        {
            sprintf(logdata,"hlf data send Successfully\n");
            LogInfo(logdata);
            sprintf(logdata,"data Send: %s\n",data);
            LogInfo(logdata);
        }
        else if(data_len_send==-1)
        {
            sprintf(logdata,"error %d \n",WSAGetLastError());
            LogInfo(logdata);
        }

        closesocket(accfd);
        return 0;

    }//child end

}//while loop end

closesocket(sockfd);
printf("socket closed\n");
WinSockCleanup();
printf("cleanup done\n");
getch();
return 0;
   }
```

i made a server and multi-client process. after the create process i need to change my current program id to child id to run the rest of the program. i want the child process to run the send and recieve part of my server

please help me regarding this.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! It's a bit unclear about which part is giving you the problem (and therefore which part we can help you with). Can you narrow down the code in your question to just the part that's relevant to your question? (we don't really need to read all your code just to find the bit that matters).

Comment: Also - can you tell us a bit more about what you mean by "shift my current program id" - do you mean you want to end the current program and continue running a forked child process? if not - please add more explanation to your question (not here in the comments).

It would also help if you give us an idea of what happened to you when you tried to run the above code. Did you get errors? can you put them here in the question too? Otherwise what did you see, and what did you expect to see?
Help us help you better by giving us a bit more to go on :)

Comment: my current code is run by the parent. after the child process is being created i want the child to run the rest of the code. not the parent. i want you to tell me how to change my current process id from parent to child

Comment: so would this be an accurate paraphrase: "I want it to fork and the child to continue and the parent to stop" ?

Comment: what happened when you looked up "fork" in your c-programming reference? ;)

Comment: yes you could say this way.

Comment: (yes, I'm being facetious... I'm just trying to figure out the issue)

Answer (score 2):

An id is assigned to the process when the process starts. There is not way to change it. This also means that you cannot shift it to anybody.

The posted piece of code is not complete. It is not that clear what it is doing.

It also seems that you are confusing `CreateProcess` with Unix `fork`. They have very different semantics.

Comment: What I see there does not make any sense. You still cannot transfer the ID of the process to accepted connection. You may be able to setup this connection as standard input of a child process. In any case you should not start `server_tcp.exe` each time you accept a connection.